Is the 8-in-one JXCT soil sensor compatible with the raspberry pi 4B?
I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and want to use the JXCT 8-in-one soil sensor with it but the documentation for the product (https://www.niubol.com/Technical-Support/Soil-Moisture-Sensor-Arduino-Code.html) uses the Arduino as its example. Then I found a similar sensor from the same company being used online but also for Arduino (https://lastminuteengineers.com/soil-npk-sensor-arduino-tutorial/) and the schematic on this website suggested that to use the sensor I should have an RS-485 transceiver module that converts a UART serial stream to RS-485. I am unsure whether this sensor will work with the Raspberry Pi using the given schematic, please help.
